SQL grouping result to half hour
I have a Firebird 2.5.9 database and I need to work on two tables. The first one stores a date and operation time. The date is stored as DATE field and 3 other fields as string (char) for year, month and day. The operation time is stored in 3 field as string (char) for hour, minute and second. The second table stores the amount in Euro as float.
With this query, I can get the amounts hour by hour:
SELECT Table1.Day AS TheDay, Table1.HH AS TH, SUM(Table2.Euro) AS EURO
FROM Table1       
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.NUMOP = Table1.NUMOP 
WHERE Table1.DAY = '2024-08-31'
GROUP BY TABLE1.DAY, TABLE1.HH

The result is the total Euros divided by hours (8, 9, 10, 11, 12), but the working hours are from 8.30 to 12.30 and the result I need to get must be 8.30, 9.00, 9.30, 10.00 .. 12.30 and 13.00 (if one or more sell happened after 12.30).
I found several answers on how get this result, but all of them work with timestamp fields, a field that is missing in both tables. I tried to change some query without any result.
These are the posts I read:

Counting Calls by Half-Hour intervals
Grouping SQL data into half hours
How can I group time by hour or by 10 minutes?

I tried to "create" the timestamp in a first select and in a second select extract the required data, but I'm not able to do the second query. The first query is:
select CAST(Table1.ANNO || '-' || Table1.MESE || '-' || Table1.GIORNO || ' ' 
   || Table1.HH || ':' || Table1.MM AS timeStamp) AS DT1 
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Giorno = '2024-08-31'

The result is a timestamp field, but I don't know how to use it for the second select.
How can I get the correct result?
NOTE: I can't change the database because it is from a third party application. I must only read the data.
After readed answers, suggestions and testing
Thank you for all your help.
I tryed to do some test ... and all of them without result.
In the first query i add the minute:
SELECT Table1.Day AS TheDay, Table1.HH AS TH,
       Table1.MM AS TM, SUM(Table2.Euro) AS EURO
FROM Table1       
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.NUMOP = Table1.NUMOP 
WHERE Table1.DAY = '2024-08-31'
GROUP BY TABLE1.DAY, TABLE1.HH, Table1.MM

and the result is

After i ad to the query the user13964273 suggestion:
SELECT Table1.Day AS TheDay, Table1.HH AS TH,
       Table1.MM AS TM, SUM(Table2.Euro) AS EURO
FROM Table1       
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.NUMOP = Table1.NUMOP 
WHERE Table1.DAY = '2024-08-31'
GROUP BY Table1.HH * 2 + Table1.MM / 30 

without casting because in the test table hours and minute are defines as integer.
I have this in DBeaver

So i correct the query with adding TABLE1.HH and Table1.MM in group by:
SELECT Table1.Day AS TheDay, Table1.HH AS TH,
       Table1.MM AS TM, SUM(Table2.Euro) AS EURO
FROM Table1       
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.NUMOP = Table1.NUMOP 
WHERE Table1.DAY = '2024-08-31'
GROUP BY TABLE1.DAY, TABLE1.HH, Table1.MM,
         Table1.HH * 2 + Table1.MM / 30 

With this result:

I'm unable to aggregate result by half hour even with first clas help from you !
How i have to write the query ?
Solved
Thanks to all, i learn a lot about time handle.
Problem solved with Simon answer.

It would be helpful if you provide a [mre] with DDL for tables and DML for example data.

In any case, have you heard of derived tables and/or common table expressions (CTE)? You don't need a "second select", you need to build a single select that does all the necessary transformation, for example using derived tables and/or CTEs.

isn't it as simple as group by (cast HH as integer) * 2 + (cast MM as integer) / 30?

A side note: the database architect who chose CHAR for hours and minutes instead on INTEGER and FLOAT for money instead of DECIMAL must be completely insane.

Try GROUP BY DAY, HH,cast(MM as int)/30

Try this (this is just pseudo code too, you might need to make some small adjustments)
SELECT 
    CAST(Table1.Year || '-' || Table1.Month || '-' || Table1.Day AS DATE) AS 
TheDate, 
    CAST(Table1.HH || ':' || Table1.MM || ':00' AS TIME) AS TheTime,
    SUM(Table2.Euro) AS TotalEuro
FROM 
    Table1
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 ON Table2.NUMOP = Table1.NUMOP 
WHERE 
    Table1.Year = '2024' AND Table1.Month = '08' AND Table1.Day = '31'
GROUP BY 
    TheDate, 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TheTime) + CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TheTime) >= 30 
THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END

Date and Time Construction:
The date and time are constructed from separate string fields into a timestamp format. Here, only the hour and minute are used to construct a time, and seconds are assumed to be zero.
Grouping by Half-Hour Intervals:
The GROUP BY clause groups records into half-hour intervals. This is done by extracting the hour from the time and adjusting it by adding 0.5 if the minutes are 30 or greater.

Thank you so much Simon for query. I have one more little, big, big problem. The DB is old and support sql dialect 1 and this dialect doen not support TIME datatype. Exist a work around?

Hi Simon, i use your query. Just a few adjustments, run and job done !! Thank you so much for your help.

Amazing @Daniele. Apologies I didnt see your other comment. Glad it works for you

Update2.
After looking at your comments and updates in the question, I'll give you a simplified example. The structure of the tables in the sample query is the same as in your examples. The grouping of the type (HH,MM/30) is applied.
Table1.



NUMOP
day
HH
MM




1
2024-08-31
10
20


2
2024-08-31
10
30


3
2024-08-31
11
20



Table2



NUMOP
AMOUNT




1
10.5


2
22.700000762939


3
50.299999237061



SELECT Table1."day" AS TheDay
  , cast(TABLE1.HH as nchar(2)) 
  || case when (cast(mm as int)/30)=0 then ':00' else ':30' end
   AS TH
  , SUM(Table2.amount) AS EURO
FROM Table1       
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.NUMOP = Table1.NUMOP 
WHERE Table1."day"='2024-08-31'
GROUP BY TABLE1."day"
  , cast(TABLE1.HH as nchar(2)), cast(mm as int)/30




THEDAY
TH
EURO




2024-08-31
10:00
10.5


2024-08-31
10:30
22.700000762939


2024-08-31
11:00
50.299999237061



fiddle
You can group by expression hh+mi/30  for rows HH+-30 min.
For example

09:40->09+40/30=10
10:20->10+20/30=10
10:30->10+30/30=11
11:20->11+20/30=11

See example



NUMOP
YY
MM
DD
HH
MI




1
2024
08
31
10
20


2
2024
08
31
10
30


3
2024
08
31
11
20






NUMOP
AMOUNT




1
10.5


2
22.700000762939


3
50.299999237061



SELECT Table1.dd AS TheDay, cast(TABLE1.HH as int)+cast(mi as int)/30 AS TH
  , SUM(Table2.amount) AS EURO
FROM Table1       
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.NUMOP = Table1.NUMOP 
WHERE Table1.yy = '2024' and Table1.mm = '08' and Table1.dd = '31'
GROUP BY TABLE1.dd, cast(TABLE1.HH as int)+cast(mi as int)/30




THEDAY
TH
EURO




31
10
10.5


31
11
73



fiddle
Update1.  For half hours
You can group by expression hh || case when mi<30 then ':00' else ':30'.
For example

09:40->09+40/30=09:30
10:20->10+20/30=10:00
10:30->10+30/30=10:30
11:20->11+20/30=11:00

SELECT Table1.dd AS TheDay
  , cast(TABLE1.HH as nchar(2)) 
  || case when cast(mi as int)<30 then ':00' else ':30' end
   AS TH
  , SUM(Table2.amount) AS EURO
FROM Table1       
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.NUMOP = Table1.NUMOP 
WHERE Table1.yy = '2024' and Table1.mm = '08' and Table1.dd = '31'
GROUP BY TABLE1.dd
  , cast(TABLE1.HH as nchar(2)) 
     || case when cast(mi as int)<30 then ':00' else ':30' end




THEDAY
TH
EURO




31
10:00
10.5


31
10:30
22.700000762939


31
11:00
50.299999237061



fiddle
As @user13964273 says, hh*2+mi/30 is perfect value for grouping.
However, the resulting value in the output list is not 'readable'. You will need to convert to the form HH:MM.
Therefore, I suggest immediately grouping by a value of type HH:MM.
Also possible group by hh, mi/30 - minimum of cast(...)

This groups 10:30 and 11:20 in the same group, which is not what the OP wants. As user13964273 says in the comments on the question, multiply the hours by two to separate them (https://dbfiddle.uk/11xfg3NL).

@MarkRotteveel, thank you. I overlooked it)
